# entity framework DbUpdateException "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" on Savechanges method

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Hey I'm building a simple application that takes data from a UI and saves it to a table in Oracle DB using EF5 I'm   trying to modify the tables using `AddOrUpdate`, and when trying to call `SaveChanges` I receive the following error:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See inner exception  for details
>
> Inner exception :  An error occurred while preparing the command
>   definition. See inner exception for details
>
> Inner exception:  operation is not valid due to the current state of
>   the object.

```
using(var dataContext = new entities())
{
   foreach (var employee in employees)
   {
       employee.Dbid_Department = departmentSequence;
       datacontext.EMPLOYEE.AddOrUpdate(employee.model);
       CurrentDepartment.departmentModel.EMPLOYEE.Add(Employee.model);  
   }

    datacontext.DEPARTMENTS.AddOrUpdate(currenDepartment.departmentModel);
    datacontext.SaveChanges ();
}
```

`departmentSequence` is a sequence that I generate from a the `MainClass` so every time the user access the application to increase the number of the existing departments the sequence will grow.

`EMPLOYEE` and `DEPARTMENTS` are tables from my database which the user updates and interacts using the UI application that I want to create.

I have an `employee` class and `currentDepartment` class that both implement I `notifypropertychange`. the `employee` possess `EMPLOYEE` as property  and `currentDepartment` possess `DEPARTMENTST` as property So I could update the tables I'm my db but also have the adventeage of `Inotifypropertychange`.

The wierd thing is that when I delete the

```
datacontext.DEPARTMENTS.AddOrUpdate(currenDepartment.departmentModel);
```

everything works fine but I still cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

I am making a wpf project using telerik control in vs 2012.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/276016/82513). I, too, was using `AddOrUpdate()` which gave me problems when I tried to upsert data with a new root object.

Comment: I tried to implement myself the AddOrUpdate method as mentioned in your seggestion using add, and remove &add methos but it still throws the same exception

Comment: What if you call `datacontext.DEPARTMENTS.AddOrUpdate(currenDepartment.departmentModel)` before the foreach?

Comment: I tried to place this method as you suggested before the foreach. Bit it's still throws the same exception. To be more specific the exception is thrown from the SaveChanges method and not from the AddOrUpdate method, it completes the AddOrUpdate method just fine but cannot save the change to db.

Comment: is there a difference in `currenDepartment.departmentModel` and `CurrentDepartment.departmentModel` or is this just a typo?

Comment: Yes I am sorry it's a typo